# SQL - After receiving rows of the same data from a SELECT INNER JOIN with a WHERE...How do I take one time what is different / unique

Tags: php, sql

I can use LIMIT to surrender myself to one row but I would like to learn how I can provide one of each rows rather than the several of the same rows / data

Goto :  http://inks-etc.com/Script/SQL/loginform.php

Username:  jason

Password:  123

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. Not many of us are likely to visit an external untrusted site.  Without any analysis, maybe you just need `SELECT DISTINCT....`

Comment: GROUP BY (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) can also be helpful, but as mentioned above, your code is good to see.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have this setup:

```
create table `some_table` (
  `uniq_id` bigint(20) unsigned not null auto_incremenet,
  `some_data` varchar(200) not null,
  `some_other_data` varchar(100) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uniq_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=260285 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

create table `some_other_table` (
  `other_id` bigint(20) unsigned not null auto_incremenet,
  `link_to_uniq_id` bigint(20) unsigned not null,
  `multiple_entry_data` varchar(100) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uniq_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=260285 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Where `some_other_table` can match `some_table` multiple times. It also sounds like you are trying something like this, and wanting one row per `uniq_id`:

```
select * from some_table
inner join some_other_table 
  on some_table.uniq_id = some_other_table.link_to_uniq_id
```

The way that you can modify this type of query to get only one entry per `uniq_id` is something like this, using the group by directive:

```
select * from some_table
inner join some_other_table 
  on some_table.uniq_id = some_other_table.link_to_uniq_id
group by some_table.uniq_id
```

Hopefully I understood your question, and hopefully this answers it.

Comment: that is awesome information to understand...give me a few minutes to read...read...read.  I am a slow learner but very persistent

Comment: I have an INNER JOIN SELECT that places two tables together. One being the SignUp and the Other is where are the products are

Comment: can you paste the whole query. change the field names and table names if yo like, but we would need the whole query to give you a definitive answer. the idea should be the same as what I have though.